# Developing Office 365 / SPO apps as a software vendor

Tags: api, office365

We are a .net based software vendor that is putting a lot of focus on cloud based software. We want to move our solutions to Office 365 / SPO, but after a lot of POC's and struggling with the API's and Azure AD authentication, we're still not clear on how to develop Office 365 web applications for generic customers in stead of our own organisation.

For starters, all sample app approaches require the Office 365 tenant domain to be hard coded in the web.config, also the app must be registered in the Office 365 Azure AD ... .

How does this flow work when we want to sell our solution to generic customers using the SharePoint App store for example? Anyone who can provide some documentation we have overlooked?

Thanks!

Regards,
Matthias

Comment: Are you aware of the [new Office 365 Rest APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892%28v=office.15%29.aspx)?

Comment: I'am that's actually the reason of my question. I read up on the new API and the new full blown SpAppReseachTracker solution. But I quite came to the same conclusion. Being that until autohosted apps are released again, the solution must run on our infrastructure and even under our url. The only thing that in located on the client's SharePoint is the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bring good news, the Office 365 APIs and tooling allows you to handle this.

There are two approaches:

1. get the customer to create the application in Azure AD and get the client ID and secret key and store it in your app somewhere...either in the UI and securely store it somewhere based on the loaded tenant in your multi-tenant provider hosted standalone web site. OR you can give them a package to install the provider hosted solution hosted on their own tenant and get them to configure the client ID and secret there too. Auto-hosted, as you mentioned, has been pulled from Office 365 as per the blog post (http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/08/update-autohosted-apps-preview-program-part-2/). Admittedly it is a manual step for setup, but does achieve what the you desire in not hosting a multi-tenant service.

OR

1. in Visual Studio change the setting (can do this in the Azure AD application in your tenant) to support "multiple Organizations". This is set when you go to Add Connected Service and select App Properties... this way you host the multi-tenant provider hosted solution in your infrastructure (can be Azure Web Sites).

Comment: Hi Jeremy,      

These are indeed the scenarios we had in mind. Good to hear we're on the right track - so many changes and updates involving Azure and Office 365, sometimes hard to keep up. :)
We're going for a multiple organisations approach, as we're talking about SME customers who are not capable of registering an Azure application. But we wanted to avoid having to host a shared infrastructure so I'm hoping to see Autohosted apps returning by the end of the year!